# Using multiple buttons in Swift is causing cascading outputs?

Tags: swift, button, output, cascading

So sorry for such a newbie question but I have no programming experience and cannot even think of how to search for an answer to my problem.

**Background**:

I am using a Wemos D1 Mini R2 to control a strip of Neopixel addressable LEDs, the sketch for this allow me to send http requests over my network to change the patterns and switch LEDs on or off etc.

I decided to have a go at writing my first IPhone App to replace using a web page and had great success with the first to button which were to switch LEDs on or off.

When I added more buttons is when i ran into trouble.

If I press the first button on the first message is sent as it should be:

```
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170221200> { URL: pttp://10.0.1.147/rainbow?fade=3000 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 7;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
} })
```

When I press the next button I get the first output and the second output?

```
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17003de00> { URL: pttp://10.0.1.147/rainbow?fade=3000 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 7;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
} })
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170220e80> { URL: pttp://10.0.1.147/wave?r=255&g=32&b=10&fade=5000 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 4;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
} })
```

and so on for the third etc:

```
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170222340> { URL: pttp://10.0.1.147/setleds?r=32&g=64&b=32&fade=5000 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 7;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
} })
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170220c60> { URL: pttp://10.0.1.147/rainbow?fade=3000 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 7;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
} })
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17403e400> { URL: pttp://10.0.1.147/wave?r=255&g=32&b=10&fade=5000 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 4;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
} })
```

I'm quite sure I am making a rooky mistake with where I have placed my code or something simple but I just cannot find the answer. Here is my code, any help would be much appreciated.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Neopixel Controller
//
//  Created by Andrew Brierley on 6/11/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Andrew Brierley. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    //START RAINBOW BUTTON HERE
    @IBAction func Rainbow(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let string1 = "http://"
        let string2 = "10.0.1.147"
        let string3 = "/rainbow?fade=3000"


        let myUrl = URL(string: string1 + string2 + string3);

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
            { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
            print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

        }
        task.resume()

    }

    // START ALL OFF BUTTON HERE
    @IBAction func AllOff(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let string1 = "http://"
        let string2 = "10.0.1.147"
        let string3 = "/ledsoff?fade=500"


        let myUrl = URL(string: string1 + string2 + string3);

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

        }
        task.resume()


    }

    //START WAVE BUTTON HERE
    @IBAction func Wave(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let string1 = "http://"
        let string2 = "10.0.1.147"
        let string3 = "/wave?r=255&g=32&b=10&fade=5000"


        let myUrl = URL(string: string1 + string2 + string3);

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

        }
        task.resume()



    }



    //START RED BUTTON HERE
    @IBAction func RED(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let string1 = "http://"
        let string2 = "10.0.1.147"
        let string3 = "/setleds?r=32&g=64&b=32&fade=5000"


        let myUrl = URL(string: string1 + string2 + string3);

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

        }
        task.resume()
    }




    //START GREEN BUTTON HERE
    @IBAction func GREEN(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let string1 = "http://"
        let string2 = "10.0.1.147"
        let string3 = "/setleds?r=000&g=255&b=000&fade=1000"


        let myUrl = URL(string: string1 + string2 + string3);

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

        }
        task.resume()

    }

    //START BLUE BUTTON HERE
    @IBAction func BLUE(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let string1 = "http://"
        let string2 = "10.0.1.147"
        let string3 = "/setleds?r=000&g=000&b=255&fade=0"


        let myUrl = URL(string: string1 + string2 + string3);

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

        }
        task.resume()

    }


    //START WHITE BUTTON HERE
    @IBAction func WHITE(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let string1 = "http://"
        let string2 = "10.0.1.147"
        let string3 = "/setleds?r=127&g=127&b=127&fade=10000000000"


        let myUrl = URL(string: string1 + string2 + string3);

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
        { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")

        }
        task.resume()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated

    }
}
```

Comment: Check whether you had bind proper button with the required method

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this but each button is bound to each procedure as above?